# Are hyperreal numbers isomorphic to formal power series?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, isomorphism-testing

I wonder whether hyperreal numbers isomorphic with formal Laurent series?

It seems that any hyperreal number can be represented in the form of Laurent series over $\omega$. For instance,

$e^{\omega}=\frac{\omega^0}{0!}+\frac {\omega^1}{1!}+\frac{\omega^2}{2!}+...+\frac{\omega^n}{n!}+...$

If so, it follows that any analytic function corresponds to a hyperreal number.

$f(x)=x$ corresponds to $\omega$

$f(x)=x^2$ corresponds to $\omega^2$

etc.

Thus operators on analytic functions are isomorphic to functions of hyperreals. Am I correct?

Comment: This is also asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117477/are-surreal-numbers-isomorphic-to-formal-power-series/1117716#1117716

Comment: The product of two Laurent series need not be a Laurent series. If you want a non-archimedean field that has well-defined multiplication and division, a good candidate is the Levi-Civita field, but the LC field doesn't have $e^\omega$ where $\omega$ is infinite. It would also be odd if a structure as "natural" as the Laurent series were isomorphic to the hyperreals, since the hyperreals are non-unique in ZFC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One problem is that the set of formal Laurent series is not a [real closed field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) (an ordered field where every positive element has a square root, and every polynomial of odd degree has a root). That particular problem would be fixed if one considered instead the real closure of the field of Laurent series, which is the field of [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) (Laurent series involving powers of $x^{1/n}$ where $n$ is allowed to vary). So the question would become: is the field of hypperreals isomorphic to the field of Puiseux series?

The answer is "certainly not"; the hyperreals are much "bigger", or it would be better to say "much more saturated" than Puiseux series. As you probably know, the hyperreals do not form a complete ordered field (only the standard real numbers do that), but they do have properties that approximate completeness. Namely, there is the $\eta_1$ property: given *countable* sets $L$ and $U$ such that every element of $L$ is less than every element of $U$, there exists an element that is an upper bound of all elements of $L$ and a lower bound of all elements of $U$. So for example: in the field of Puiseux series (and taking $x$ to be an infinitesimal element), there is a pretty big gap between all the rational constants (forming an $L$) and the $x^{-1/n}$ (forming a $U$). The hyperreals fill in such gaps.

(Added on request.) The hyperreals thus form an ordered field extension of the field of Puiseux series, and admits elements such as $\sin \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is an infinitesimal.

Comment: By the way, $\sin \omega$ does belong to the formal power series but does not to hyperreals, is this wrong or correct?

Comment: If the hyperreals are bigger, can we say that the formal power series (or converging power series or analytic functions) are isomorphic to a subset of hyperreals?

Comment: (1) No, you can form a hypperreal $\sin \omega$. (2) Yes, one can regard the field of formal power series as an ordered subfield of the hyperreals.

Comment: I think the last comment is very valuable, can you please add this to the answer?

Comment: "No, you can form a hypperreal $\sin ω$". - hmm, I am curious, will it be an infinitesimal?

Comment: Yes, $\sin \omega$ will be infinitesimal.

Comment: Oh, it seems you misunderstood me! In my question I meant $\omega$ to be infinite, as usually in non-standard analysis it is postulated to be equal to the first ordinal $\omega$.

Comment: So $\sin (1/\omega)=\sin \varepsilon$ is definitely a hyperreal and infinitesimal, but what about $\sin \omega$ then?

Comment: Oh, I see (and sorry I was confusing). Right, the way that Puiseux series are usually set up, the $x$ will be infinitesimal [I edited a mistake here in my answer; I often get confused which way it should go], and there, there is no such series for that would express an infinite element such as $e^y$ where $y = x^{-1}$.

Comment: So if we take $\omega$ as infinite element, there are formal power series (like $\sin \omega$) which are not hyperreals apparently, so the power series seems to be a bigger set than hyperreals?

Comment: Anixx, I think a problem here is exactly how you are defining the order if you are considering $x$ to be infinite and considering power series expressions such as $\sin x$. Is this going to be positive or negative (or zero)? I think you have to be careful here!

Comment: Actually to be more precise I was referring to Conway's $No$ ohio.edu/people/ehrlich/Unification.pdf

Comment: Todd, one may refer to $\sin(\omega)$ or $e^\omega$ for any hyperreal $\omega$, including infinite elements, simply by appealing to the transfer principle---every function on the reals has a nonstandard analogue, which satisfies all the same first-order expressible properties in the hyperreals that the original function did in the standard reals.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I was confused it seems; thanks for setting me straight! I'm going to use my mod powers to edit my comment now.

Comment: Anixx, based on your most recent comment I think you might be confusing the *hyperreals* with the *surreals*, which are two very different things. In particular, there's no "special" element of 'the' hyperreals which we deem "$\omega$."

Comment: @Noah S I think in $No(\omega_1)$ there is. But I still would like a clarification.

Comment: Again, "$No$" is from the *surreals*, not the hyperreals.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to point out that it is not true that every every
hyperreal can be represented by a Laurent series in the way you
describe.

(Let me assume that by the term "hyperreals", you mean a
nonstandard elementary extension of the reals, with the transfer
property. It is not really correct to speak of "the" hyperreals,
since it is possible to have non-isomorphic fields with these
properties.)

In particular, what I claim is that it is *never* the case for a nonzero
hyperreal number $x$ that the hyperreal analogue of $e^x$ obeys
the equation $$e^x=
\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac {x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\cdots,$$
if what is meant is that $n$ ranges only over the standard natural
numbers, which is how I take your example. In particular, the sequence of finite partial sums of
this series does not converge in the hyperreals, unless $x$ is
zero. So the series is simply not meaningful in this way in the
hyperreals.

Rather, the right way to handle series in the hyperreals is that
they should have nonstandard terms, including also the terms for
nonstandard natural numbers $n$. In particular, the transfer
principle implies that the meaning of $e^x$ in the hyperreals is
given by the nonstandard series representation
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{x^n}{n!},$$ where $n$ here ranges over all the nonstandard
natural numbers, not just the standard finite natural numbers.

The difference between the two series is precisely the nonstandard
part of the series, and this difference cannot be visible to the
hyperreal field, since from it you could define the standard cut,
which would violate the transfer principle.

Comment: The number 3 is a nonzero hyperreal number.  Are you saying in the hyperreals that $e^3$ is not $1 + 3 + 3^2/2! + ... + 3^n/n! + ...$ where $n$ runs over the nonnegative integers?

Comment: In the hyper-real field, that sum does not converge if you use only standard $n$. You have to include the terms with nonstandard $n$, and in that case, you'll get $e^3$. Perhaps it would help you to think about the fact that in the hyperreals, the number $e^3$ is surrounded by a tiny interval of hyperreals infinitesimally close to $e^3$, and the standard part of the series is only getting you up to that whole interval and not to the center of it, which is what the rest of the series does.

Comment: At first your response really surprised me, but now I think I see the problem: convergence in the hyperreals uses its order topology and an infinitesimal neighborhood of the real number $e^3 = 20.085...$ is isolated from all those classical partial sums I wrote down above, and thus they don't converge to $e^3$. Is that all, or is there more to it than that? For the same reason, I guess, no classical power series centered at $0$ converges in the hyperreals except at 0, e.g., if $0 < |x| < 1$ in the reals then the usual geom. series $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...$ does not converge to $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: Yes, you've got it now.